# How can I set only a view of two views added to a panel to be shown as accordion?

Tags: views, panels

I have a panel page which contains 2 views. I only want a single view to display as accordion. If I set the style setting of that view to *Accordion*, nothing happens; if I set the style setting of the panel to *Accordion*, both the views become accordions.

How can I set only a view of two views added to a panel to be shown as accordion?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using these modules :

[Panels Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_accordion)

> Panels Accordion provides an accordion display within Panels. By using
>   accordions you can fit more content into smaller areas and allow your
>   users to expand each section as needed. This uses the existing jQuery
>   file for the accordion effect. The layout settings allow you to choose
>   the action, effect, and speed for accordions.

[views Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion)

> Views Accordion provides a display style plugin for the Views module.
>   It will take the results and display them as a JQuery accordion, using
>   the first field as the header for the accordion rows.

Comment: I started off with these modules and came across the above mentioned issue. If I make panel an accordion, all views inside it are becoming accordions.